# Eclipse/Java: easy way to consolidate classes source code without individual copy/paste?

Tags: java, eclipse, presentation

For my Java assignments, I usually have to copy/paste my source code into my report. Business as usual. However, for bigger projects it is kind of annoying to copy and paste a bunch of classes.

Does anyone know if Eclipse has a function that allows you to view all your classes in one file, or something like that?

If that is confusing: *I want to be able to view all my classes for a given project in a single document/viewer/something without copying and pasting.* Can it be done with relative ease?

---

**EDIT:** As a commenter noted, preserving syntax highlighting would be great. Solutions that can retain that feature would be nice.

Comment: and how about syntax highlighting ...

Comment: @jeppi Syntax highlighting is preserved through copy/paste, and it would be nice for that to be retained in an alternative method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that the fastest way is not using Eclipse, but external tools like bash scripting. For example, in Linux's shell or Windows [Cygwin terminal](http://www.cygwin.com/) you can use:

```
find src_folder -type f  | egrep "\.java$" | 
  while read -r file_name  
do 
   cat "$file_name" >> myoutputfile.txt 
done
```

So what it actually does is find all the files which have the `.java` extension, print them and redirect and append `stdout` to  `myoutputfile.txt` .

Comment: Good thinking; I doubt this will preserve syntax highlighting, though. +1 since I didn't mention that in the question (I am going to add it, though).

Comment: Then you can instead redirect stream to `myoutputfile.java` and open it, for example, with Gedit or other simple syntax highlighter. Even not being syntactically correct (you cannot define more than one non-static class per file) you'll get syntax highlighting. If you print the document in PDF or copy/paste to word/libreoffice (depending on the editor) you'll get a full highlighted document